# How to implement a check member method in constant time O(1) for a queue list?

Tags: python, list, data-structures, queue

I want to implement a check member method for a Queue list (self implementation) in python without iterate over all members to check and without sacrifice the order.

I have the following FIFOqueue implementation:

```
class FIFOqueue(object):
 """Initialize with a list"""
def __init__(self, elements):
    self.list = elements

def pop(self):
     """Return the oldest element of the list (last index)"""
    return self.list.pop()

def insert(self, element):
     """Insert a new element at the end"""
    self.list = self.list + [element]
```

**How can add to the above class a check member method in constant time O(1)?**

Comment: You can't; that's why `dict`s exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep an O(1) complexity, do not use list, prefer dict, especially [OrderedDict in python 2X](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to keep insertion order, or standards dict for python 3.6+ (keep insertion order now).

[Here you can find time complexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) for standard operations on object in python